# joomla 2.5 pass default value to new item

Tags: joomla

I like to create a new item out of a backend list view. 
For the new Item I'd like to pass a default value that depends on the current list (actual year).

How can i do this with Joomla 2.5?

I'm able to pass the value to the controller for the new item (by JRequest::getInt('AValue') ) on current controller by overwriting the add() method.

```
public function add()
{
    $AValue = JRequest::getInt('AValue');
    if($AValue == null)
    {
        $AValue = 2012;
    }
    parent::add();
}
```

I've tried to get the model and assign the value to it but the getModel() method returned a different object than the one used in the definitive view.

Any Idea how to get the Value to the new Item's form?

Thanks

Comment: Can't you pass the value directly in the form? Are you using JTable? More information / code from your component would be necessary to understand what are you doing.

Answer (score 0):

Situation:
Have a List of events during a Soccer saison. If I choose the Saison from a list, I'll get another list with all assigned events to that saison.
the List of Events during a Saison is called by:

com_mycomponent/view=eventlists&saisonid=2011

This will show me a list with all events assigned to the saison 2011

Now I'd like to create a new event for saison 2011.

Add button will call: eventlist.add

```
MyComponentControllerEventList extends JControllerForm
```

during the add operation I'd like to pass the saison (2011) somehow to the form.

Model contains:

```
public function getTable($type = 'EventList', $prefix = 'MyComponentTable', $config = array())
{
    return JTable::getInstance($type, $prefix, $config);
}   

public function getForm($data = array(), $loadData = true) 
{       
// Get the form.        
$form = $this->loadForm('com_mycomponent.eventlist', 'eventlist', array('control' => 'jform', 'load_data' => $loadData));
if (empty($form))
{           
    return false;       
}       
return $form;   
}   

protected function loadFormData()   
{       
    // Check the session for previously entered form data.      
    $data = JFactory::getApplication()->getUserState('com_mycomponent.edit.eventlist.data', array());
    if (empty($data)){          
    // generate an empty item
        $data = $this->getItem();
    }       
    return $data;
}
```

So it's straight forward.

The View is also kind of default.

```
public function display($tpl = null) 
{
    // get the Data
    $form = $this->get('Form');
    $item = $this->get('Item');
    // Check for errors.
    if (count($errors = $this->get('Errors'))) 
    {
        JError::raiseError(500, implode('<br />', $errors));
        return false;
    }
    // Assign the Data
    $this->form = $form;
    $this->item = $item;

    // Display the template
    parent::display($tpl);
}
```

Any thought's on this?
Thanks

Comment: Additional information: One field in the database specifies the saison that the event belongs to.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this-

http://docs.joomla.org/API15:JRequest/setVar

```
public function add()
{
    $AValue = JRequest::getInt('AValue');
    if($AValue == null)
    {
        JRequest::setInt('AValue',date('Y'));
    }
    parent::add();
}
```